# How to convert Midi file variables to millisecond timestamps in javascript

Tags: javascript, midi, web-midi

I currently have a midi file parsed into a JSON object. Below is an image of the midi object in my browser console.

[image: midi JSON object in browser console]

My goal is to take this data (marked in red) and convert each item in the list to timestamps in milliseconds.

From my research, I know the meaning of the "`deltaTime`" property and I believe the "`timeDivision`" value of `192` (underlined in the image above) should be related to the tempo of the midi file.

However, because of my sparse knowledge of the maths behind midi file values, I don't know how to convert all that information to milliseconds. I'm certain it must be a relatively simple math equation. But I'm really lost. I'm trying to build an object that should look like this and match the current millisecond time of the JSON object

[[image: image of expected end results]

How do I convert the "`timeDivision`" value combined with the list of individual "`deltaTime`" values to milliseconds?

Even a basic answer would suffice. I just need to understand the math behind those values.

Comment: how did you get from the picture of the object to the picture of the expected result? manually?

Comment: [Images](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are OK but aren't mandatory. Code as a [mcve] is required 99% of the time.

Comment: Please tell us **exactly** which MIDI libraries you're using - because [the official WebMIDI API doesn't expose structured MIDI messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MIDIMessageEvent) (only raw bytes in a `Uint8Array`), and none of the other JS+MIDI libraries I found [have data-members like `deltaTime` and `metaType``, like WebmidiJS](https://webmidijs.org/api/classes/WebMidi#eventMap).

Comment: `timeDivision` does not refer to tempo.  It means that the `deltaTime` numbers are all in units of 1/192nd of a beat.  Have you read the MIDI specs?

Comment: The default tempo is 120 beats per minute.

Comment: @JaromandaX, Not quite. However, I'm well aware that should be the results because that track represents positions for syllables in a song (for a karaoke) app. I have an xml file for this same track and that is what the values are. The challenge is just getting the midi-only approach to work.

Comment: @Dai, I'm using the midi-parser-js library on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/midi-parser-js) (in a browser context).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Tim Roberts. I understand that now. Yes, I checked the specs but not so comprehensively. I found it really hard to find documentation for those exact terms `termDivision` because I think the midi to JSON parser I'm using has unique terminology names. Will take a closer look at the specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Delta value units**

Midi files may contain one or more meta events to  specify tempo in terms of the number of microseconds per quarter note. The default tempo is 120 BPM.

In MIDI a "quarter note" corresponds to a single beat. This may be because crotchet beats in 4/4 time are quarter the length of a semibreve, also known as a "whole note".

Each quarter note is divided into a number of "pulses per quarter note" (PPQN) where each pulse generates a playback timing tick. (As an aside, high values of the PPQN clock period lead to quantization of playback note lengths, whereas low periods can reproduce more subtle timing variations a musician might have used when recording a piece.)

The value of PPQN is set in the "master track header" (MThd) chunk, in the last two bytes of the chunk, which has a length of 6 bytes. The field name of the PPQN value shown in documentation is `Division`, while in the proxy object listing it has been labelled "timeDivision",  with a value of 192.

*Delta values are the number of PPQN ticks since the previous Midi event or meta-event in the source MIDI file.*

**Delta time conversion to microseconds**

So to convert delta times to microseconds, you could use the formula

```
 microSeconds = deltaTime / Division  // delta time in quarter notes
              * microSeconds_per_quarter_note;   // taken from the binary value supplied in a tempo meta event.
```

The `microSeconds_per_quarter_note` for the default tempo of 120 BPM would be

```
 (60 / BPM)    // length of 1 beat in seconds
 * 1000000     // in microseconds
```

**Warning**

Detecting tempo changes within a midi file requires full and accurate parsing of raw MIDI data: the byte sequences for tempo change may occur within System exclusive messages (perhaps others?)  as a valid part of their content. I am not in a position to comment on the accuracy or completeness of JSON file data shown in the post.

Variations: Some midi files may contain SMPTE timing information not covered above.

**See Also**

- [Pulses per quarter note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulses_per_quarter_note) (Wikipedia)
- [Timing in Midi Files](https://sites.uci.edu/camp2014/2014/05/19/timing-in-midi-files/) (UCI post)
- [MIDI technical documentation](http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/miditech.htm) (midi.teraconaudio)
- [Standard MIDI File (SMF) Format](http://midi.teragonaudio.com/tech/midifile.htm) (midi.teraconaudio)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @traktor. Would love to upvote it but it's a new account so I can't.